# Show different content according to a radio button

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, radio-button, haml

I have a form with some fields and a radio button, and I would like to show different contents according to the radio button. This is my _form for the Course.rb

```
.inputs
    = f.input :name, input_html: {class: 'span' }  
    = f.input :cod, input_html: {class: 'span' }

    = f.association :type
            :as => :radio_buttons,  
            :required => true
```

I also have the model Type.rb which has id, name (1 - Undergraduate and 2 - Graduate). I wanna show a different content according to the radio button. However, I have no idea how can I do it. Can I use JQuery?

For example, if the user choose graduate, I wanna show some fields/link/div.. If he or she choose undergraduate, I'll show different things.

I tried to put a if (@course.type_id == 1), but id doesn't work because I don't know which number I got yet.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you managed to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use javascript to manipulate the DOM according to the chosen radio button.

Example, in coffeescript:

```
jQuery ->
$("input[name='type_id']").change ->
    if this.val() == 1
      // show some information somewhere
    else if this.val() == 2
      // show another information somewhere
```

Let me know if I can improve the answer :)

Comment: Yeah! Thank you so much!
I made just little changes, but it is working!

Answer (score 0):

```
  selected_val = $('input[name=radioName]:checked', '#myFormid').val();
  check if selected_val 
  //do something
```